# How to storing Sub query in variable. MySql

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

```
SET @variable1 = (SELECT id FROM table2);
update vars set unq=1 where id IN @variable1
```

how to perform the above query. because there are one million rows and sub query taking too much time for update. so how to save all ids of table2 in var and use in second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `in` with a subquery takes too long, try rewriting with a join:

```
update vars join
       table2
       on vars.id = table2.id
    set unq = 1;
```

An index on `table2.id` would help speed up performance as well.

Comment: ( Query took 13.3356 sec wow!) can you please see this too...
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52609/fasted-way-to-perform-simple-operations-on-1-million-rows-mysql-innodb-table